# Which of the following are true? Problem in analysis

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f\colon [0,1]\to (0,1)$ be a continuous mapping, then which of the following is not true?

1) if $f(0)< f(1)$ then $f([0,1])$ must be equal to $[f(0),f(1)]$.

2) There must exist $x \in (0,1)$ such that $f(x)=x$

I think both are not true.

For 2) $f(x)=\frac{x}{2}$ is a counterexample. Am I right?

Comment: The problem with $f(x)=\frac{x}{2}$ is that it doesn't map $0$ to $(0,1)$.

Comment: For the second one, try to draw it.
The solution $f(x)=x$ represents the graph of $f$ intersecting the diagonal line, so you need to draw a continuous function that starts above the line, and ends below it.

Comment: oh yes right...

Comment: What is that $\varepsilon$? Did you mean $x \in (0,1)$?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 1) is not true; one can easily construct a function which takes maximum value at $x=1/2$.
On the other hand, 2) is true; for example, consider another continuous function $g(x):=f(x)-x$ and observe that $g(0) >0$ and $g(1) <0$.